# Write large file to HTTP response

Tags: c#-4.0

I am currently developing an asp application with c# .net. I have to query a large(10GB) SQLite database and write the data as CSV format to HTTP response.
I am doing this

```
        /*query database, use string builder to create a csv*/
        Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", result.Length.ToString());
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"Data.csv\"");
        Response.Write(result);
        Response.Flush();
```

Which works file with small amount of data. But when the file size increases I get a OutOfMemoryException. I think using StringBuilder to create a string is causing the issue. I can not figure out any way to solve the issue. Can anyone please help me resolve this?

Comment: What is the aim do you want to achieve? Do you want to download this file on client or something else? Do your application is asp.net mvc or webforms?

Comment: i don't think is good strategy to use the http to do this. I thought was javascript but its actually c# then in server side. But how the client will handle this? will respond with the same impact i think ...

Comment: On the client side client will see a file download prompt. And the application is on webforms. @Kirill

Comment: what if you temporarily create an ftp server for this file and send the link for the ftp to the client?

Comment: @memosdp I thought about that. In that case I will have to maintain file name to avoid duplicate file names.

Comment: this is easy ... do it with the date and time as suffix or prefix or the whole name

Comment: @memosdp that might be an option. but i am trying to do this in real time. i will consider your idea if i can not find any other alternative way. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually solved the problem.
I did this

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"Data.csv\"");
foreach(var item in dbItem)
{
     /*create a string with database data*/
     Response.write(string);
     Response.Flush();
}
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to read data by `DataReader` and write it into `Response.OutputStream`. 
Something like this:

```
SqlDataReader dr;
//initialize datareader to your table
...
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"Data.csv\"");
var writer = new StreamWriter(Response.OutputStream);
while (dr.Read())
{
    writer.WriteLine(dr[1].ToString()+";"+dr[2].ToString()+";"+dr[3].ToString()+";");
    Response.Flush();
}
```